# "High" Quality Pixel Art Games (varying the scale factor)

Tags: art, pixel-art

Currently I'm developing a pixel art game and I was looking through the different styles to see which one would be the best for my game. The classic style is to draw all sprites/textures at a 1x scale offscreen to an image and then when you render the frame, scale the image up some amount to fit the window. The smaller the textures, the more pixelated the graphics look.

However, I also saw games like Realm of the Mad God, and I was wondering how they do their drawing. The game is mostly pixelated, with some exceptions. Most notable are the high quality shadows, high quality text and the very thin black outlines on all the sprites. I was wondering how this can be achieved. The only thing I can think of is the scale everything separately (game elements x3, outlines x1, shadows x1, etc...) so you can mix pixelated elements with high quality textures. Is this the right approach? What would this look like in LibGDX and game development in general?

Realm of the Mad God example.
[image]

One last thing, if anyone knows, could you tell me which of these two styles Terraria uses, and if its the first style, what the "base" scale is? (resolution of the game screen at 1x scale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple - you just have your textures made out of e.g. 8x8 pixels blocks and use 1px outlines and smooth shadows.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't realize it was this simple :(